# Why am I unable to get a reply from the api endpoint with axios

Tags: reactjs

I am sending a request to an endpoint but it doesn't return a response. The endpoint is available.

Here is my code:

```
import './App.css'
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import Login from './login/Login'
import axios from 'axios'



export default function App() {
  
const[isLogged,setIsLogged] = useState(false);


  const[csrf,setCsrf] = useState("");

  const url = 'https://mtstorez.000webhostapp.com/app/store/welcome'

  
  //get login status of user
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post(url, {
      key1: 'value1',
      key2: 'value2'
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('AJAX request successful');
      //setData(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('AJAX request failed');
      //setError(error.message);
    });
  }, []);



  
  return (

  
    <main>

      {
        isLogged ? <div> <Dashboard/> </div> :
      <Login/>
      }
    </main>
  )
}
```

I tried jsonplaceholder endpoint to generate fake data and it worked. I also allowed request from all origin and  it didn't work also.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Open your network tab in the developer console and let me know what it says there.

Comment: It would be useful to see the error message you get

Comment: It replies with ajax request failed from the catch error

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your endpoint using postman and got back a proper response both with POST and GET.

However, when tried from a browser, only the GET request performs as expected. I've set up a reproductible example here :https://github.com/jbrocher/question-76220440. The POST version fails with a preflight error.

The difference of behavior between postman and the browser points to a CORS issue.

From the test I've done with Postman, it would seem the endpoint returns the same thing both using GET and POST so I would suggest using the GET version as I did in the repository I linked. I you have control over the endpoint, should verify your CORS settings as well.

Comment: Thanks so much.. I removed the data sent with the request and it now works.